# How to create 'onkeydown' event in code behind in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to add live search feature in my web project, with which I can refresh `gridview` whenever someone types in the text box. As soon as I type `a` or `arun` or `stu` or any word in the textbox, the `gridview` should be refresh.

I know how to refresh `gridview`, but the `text_changed` event comes after we defocus the textbox, i.e. moving to next control. In short when we get focus out of the textbox then the textbox event works, but I want to perform the code behind function when anyone even types a single word in the textbox.

Project is in ASP.NET using VB, but it would be OK if one can provide a C# solution.

Comment: is your textbox a runar server control?

Comment: Ya, its an asp.net textbox .. runat server ..

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's `change` event on the textbox to refresh. Eg:

```
$('#yourTextBox').change(function () {
  // either handle updating the gridview yourself

  // or click an invisible search button:
  $('#someHiddenSearchButton').click();
});
```

Comment: can you tell me how would i call a code behind function using javascript .. in which i can pass the new value of textbox to that code behind function ..

Comment: With jQuery, you can either write a web service or use a [page method](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a button as following[its style says its display is none]:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="CallServerMethod" 
 OnClick="Button3_Click" OnClientClick="CallServerMethod()" style="display:none" />
```

In the OnClick function in the code behind write your required function.

Now in you text box:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeyup="CallServerMethod()" 
ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Now write the javascript function as following:

```
function CallServerMethod() {
document.getElementById('Button3').click();
}
```

**Summary:**

You write the function to be executed in the `OnClick event of a hidden button` and then you simulate the click of this hidden button through javascript via `onkeyup of the textbox`.

**OR**

To send a parameter:`alert('<%CodeBehindFunction('+ Param +')%>');` in the onkeyup function of the textbox.

Comment: i want to call a code behind function onkeyup event .. can u suggest me some thing for that ???

Comment: I ve made the necessary code to call in the code behind function. see the answer and let me know if you seek more help.

Comment: btw why do you want to send parameters, is it to send character typed in the textbox, if so you already have it in the textbox.text, no need to send as parameter.

Comment: ok i thought, until we focus out the textbox the value might not be changed in textbox.text .. thats why .. thanX a lot :)